# Copy and modify records with access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-insert

This seems so simple, I need to select all records from one table where one field equals a number in a forms text box, then modify that field, and paste the records back into the same table. I would like to do this using VBA in a button's event procedure. Thinking something like:

```
DoCmd.Runsql "INSERT INTO QuoteLines (QuoteID,ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice) SELECT (MAX(Quotes.QuoteID) AS Expr1,ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice) WHERE QuoteID = Forms![MakeQuote].[QuoteNum]"
```

Access says missing operator in the "MAX(Quotes.QuoteID) AS Expr1" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Realised you wanted records from QuoteLines to be inserted into QuoteLines.

Try using the DMax() function, or using a subquery.

```
"INSERT INTO QuoteLines (QuoteID,ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice) " _
& "SELECT (DMax(""QuoteID"",""Quotes""),ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice) " _
& "FROM QuoteLines WHERE QuoteID = Forms![MakeQuote].[QuoteNum]"
```

Examples on using SELECT INTO [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: I think we're close. It came back, Syntax error (comma) in query expression DMax(""QuoteID"",""Quotes""),ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice)

Comment: Perhaps try
`"INSERT INTO QuoteLines (QuoteID,ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice) " _
& "SELECT " & DMax("QuoteID","Quotes") & ",ItemID,QuotedQTY,QuotedPrice " _
& "FROM QuoteLines WHERE QuoteID = Forms![MakeQuote].[QuoteNum]"`

Comment: Access didn't like the underscores, but without those it seems to be working. :) THANK YOU.

Comment: The underscores are line continuation commands. See [this link here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/_AtEndOfLine.htm) for a short quick intro on them.

Glad you got it going!

Comment: Well that will be helpful, I was just putting everything in one long line this whole time.